# Java application fail to send data to UDP server at localhost

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I have this small code which is supposed to send data to UDP server and to recieve response data:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class TestRcon {
    private static DatagramSocket ds;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ds = new DatagramSocket(27024);
            byte[] data;

            data = new String("ÿÿÿÿrcon pass status").getBytes();

            System.out.println("Send:" + new String(data));

            DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(data, 0, data.length,
                    InetAddress.getByName("88.88.88.88"), 28960);

            ds.send(dp);
            byte[] rec = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket dp2 = new DatagramPacket(rec, 1024);
            ds.receive(dp2);

            System.out.println("Recieve:" + new String(rec));

            ds.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (ds != null)
                ds.close();
        }

    }
}
```

When I send data from my computer to server computer where UDP server runs, everything works fine. But when I run same Java application on that server computer (correct me if I'm wrong, but in that case application treats UDP server as it runs at localhost) nothing happens.

Few infos:

1. I tried to pass: localhost, 127.0.0.1, InetAddress.getLocalHost() instead of 88.88.88.88. Didn't help.
2. There is already one application that runs successfully on server and sends data to UDP server.

What could be wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Obviously this is not a code problem if it works remotely. You have a network/server config issue.

Comment: @BrianRoach Ok, but how I should treat IP? As localhost or 88.88.88.88?